# Book claims several theorems in the theory of equations are wrong

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I was reading this book: [Anomalies in Net Present Value...](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=5HknDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&dq=descartes%20rule%20of%20signs%20even&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKj73-0IeAAxUJ_rsIHWmqBjkQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=descartes%20rule%20of%20signs%20even&f=false) where the author claims that Descartes' rule of signs is wrong and Fourier-Boudan theorm is wrong on section 4.2 on page 134.

The author also claims that Vincent's theorem is also wrong on page 141.

I don't have sufficient knowledge to argue his opinion, but are the mentioned theorems wrong?

I tried to locate the resources he based his claim on but could not do this through web search from the geographic location I live in and I have no access to an academic library.

I don't expect a long answer, maybe few sentences would suffice to explain the matter. I have a feeling I am missing something big.

Thank you.

Comment: If that claim were on a web page button I would call it [clickbait](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clickbait#:~:text=click·%E2%80%8Bbait%20ˈklik%2Dˌbāt,of%20dubious%20value%20or%20interest). No, Descartes' rule of signs is not wrong. Go find a good book and read the proof if you want, it is not difficult to understand why it is true.

Comment: It seems the author did not prove anything?

Comment: I'm amused by the author's claim on page 137 that *for* ***a*** *given equation*, the number of negative signs of the coefficients grows without bound.

This makes me think that the author is instead considering something like power series or laurent series (limits of sequences of partial sums of polynomials and/or rational functions), rather than polynomials. More so because the equation he's talking about is a special case of the "polynomial" equation $$y=a_1x^{-1}+a_2x_2^{-2}+a_3x^{-3}+\cdots+a_nx^{-n}.$$

Comment: You might have uncovered a scamming scheme going on in Springer and Palgrave Macmillan. The author, and others referencing this book too, are just publishing word salads. Open a random book from them and it doesn't say anything meaningful.

Comment: "Anomalies in the Binomial Theorem and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra" (part of the title of section $5$) ah yes, truly the theorems which every mathematician, except the author of this book, would certainly overlook falsehoods in...

Comment: In the past they have had to remove randomly generated papers that made it to publications. See [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2014.14763). I don't know if these books are randomly/automatically generated, but it looks like Springer and others will need to check again among books. The Nigerian prince is now in the publishing business.

Comment: If you see claim "theorem routinely published in undergrad textbooks is wrong", you can safely ignore the claim, usually together with the entire book/paper that includes such claim. (google books no longer shows even the necessary page, but reading the text is redundant in this case)